# Manually login link

Tags: magento-1.9, login, link

I have a specific form in a CMS page and I want the user to have the option to log in with his account instead of filling out the form.

I inserted a link to the login page but I was not able to set the **referer** on the link, so the user could be redirected back to the same CMS page that he was.

I discovered that the referer is the URL (string) of my page encoded in base64, e.g.:
`mysite.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9iZWxsYWxhc2guY29tLz9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/`

But when I hard code this in the `href` attribute of my link, the redirect after the login is not working.

Since this is a CMS page, is there a way to do that in the frontend of Magento?

Ps.: I have `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard...` set to NO

Thank you!